# Dynamic route and controller with ng-class

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, templates, dynamic

I'm try to create dynamic framework with angularjs
here is my plan ... the user have to add the new templateUrl and controller from json file like this **templates.json**

```
{
  "pages" : [
    {
    "name"        : "home",
    "tempUrls"    : "views/home",
    "controller"  : "HomeController"
    },
    {
      "name"        : "about",
      "tempUrls"    : "views/about",
      "controller"  : "AboutController"
    },
    {
      "name"        : "contact",
      "tempUrls"    : "views/contact",
      "controller"  : "ContactController"
    }
  ]
}
```

from here our job to create for hem the controller and templateUrl with the page name in angularjs like this **hours.js**

```
var hours = angular.module('hours', ['ngRoute']);

var $routeProviderReference;
var currentRoute;
hours.config(function($routeProvider){
    $routeProviderReference = $routeProvider;
})
.run(['$route', '$http', '$rootScope', function($route, $http, $rootScope){
    $http.get("templates.json").success(function(data){
        var loop = 0, currentRoute;
        for(loop = 0; loop < data.pages.length; loop++){
            currentRoute = data.pages[loop];
            var routeName = "/" + currentRoute.name;
            $routeProviderReference.when(routeName, {
                templateUrl: currentRoute.tempUrls,
                controller : currentRoute.controller,
                resolve: {
                    param: function()
                    {
                        return currentRoute.resolve;
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        $route.reload();
    });
}]);

hours.controller(currentRoute.controller, function($scope){
    $scope.pageClass = 'page-' + currentRoute.name;
});
```

and here is the **index.html**

```
<div ng-class="{{pageClass}}" ng-view></div>
```

and here is the static version from angularJS before i converted to dynamic

```
var hours = angular.module('hours', ['ngRoute']);

hours.config(function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'views/page-home.html',
            controller: 'homeController'
        })
});

hours.controller('homeController', function($scope){
    $scope.pageClass = 'page-home';
});
```

i hope really someone can help!!!

Answer (score 0):

This is how I am used to working with [ng-class](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass). It does appear to have multiple formats. This style requires single curly braces.

```
ng-class="{ myClass: ExpressionThatResolvesTrueOrFalse }"
```

So if the expression resolves true, then Angular will add myClass to the element. If it resolves false, it will not add the class. It will watch the value of the expression for changes as part of the normal scope digest.

I believe the model format does not use braces at all and is more like:

```
ng-class="pageClass"
```

Comment: Angular's [ng-class](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass) documentation. Also, he could use `ng-class="pageClass"` - it may be helpful to add that :)

Comment: Thanks @Sean3z, was editing as you posted, and you are completely right. In fact, it's been awhile since I reviewed the docs myself.